# Can't pass argument to Docker file in run Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, yaml, environment-variables

I have been trying to get ENV variable in google cloud and to be injected in my app. I'm not being able to understand or getting the results I want when the app is deployed. I'm right now trying to inject the variables as an ARG to the DOCKER FILE but always getting an error.

```html
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '--no-cache'
      - '--build-arg MONGO_URL=${_MONGO_URL}'
      - '-t'
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - .
      - '-f'
      - Dockerfile
    id: Build
```

The code above is my YAML file with the steps in the build. And I have the --build-arg cmd.

```
ARG MONGO_URL

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

ENV GRAPHQL_URL=${GRAPHQL_URL}
ENV MONGO_URL=${MONGO_URL}
```

And I expect a Arg in my docker file but then I have this error:

```
Step #0 - "Build": invalid argument "MONGO_URL=hola" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out i wasn't passing the --build-arg correctly:

```
        steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '--no-cache'
      - '--build-arg' 
      - 'MONGO_URL=${_MONGO_URL}'
      - '-t'
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - .
      - '-f'
      - Dockerfile
    id: Build
```